# Array2 gets set to a array1 unexpectedly in Svelte

Tags: javascript, arrays, svelte

For some reason, images2 gets set to the same thing as images1 instead of galleryData.splice(0, 3), this is not what I want to happen.

The second console.log(images2) prints what galleryData.splice(0, 3) returns

```
<script>
    export let galleryData

    //Logic for organizing images
    let showAdditionalImages = false
    let images1 = []
    let images2 = []
    if(galleryData.length >= 3) {
        console.log("images2")
        console.log(images2)
        images1 = galleryData.slice(0, 3)
        images2 = galleryData.splice(0, 3)
        console.log("images2")
        console.log(images2)
        console.log("galleryData.splice")
        console.log(galleryData.splice(0, 3))
    } else {
        images1 = galleryData
    }


    let enlargeBool = false
    let enlargedImage
    const enlargeImage = (imageData) => {
        enlargedImage = {
            URL: imageData.URL,
            name: imageData.name
        }
        enlargeBool = true
    }
</script>

<main>
    <div id="gallery" class="gallery">
        <!--Preview for showing the list of images-->
        {#each images1 as imageData}
            <button on:click={() => {enlargeImage(imageData)}} class="gallery-image">
                <span>{imageData.name}</span>
                <img src={imageData.URL} alt={imageData.name}/>
            </button>
        {/each}
        {#if images2.length > 0}
            {#if showAdditionalImages}
                {#each images2 as imageData}
                    <button on:click={() => {enlargeImage(imageData)}} class="gallery-image">
                        <span>{imageData.name}</span>
                        <img src={imageData.URL} alt={imageData.name}/>
                    </button>
                {/each}
            {:else}
                <button class="load-images" on:click={() => {showAdditionalImages = true}}>Load Additional Images</button>
            {/if}
        {/if}
        <!--Code for the enlarged image when clicked-->
        {#if enlargeBool}
            <button on:click={() => {enlargeBool = false}} class="enlarged-image">
                <div>{enlargedImage.name}</div>
                <img src={enlargedImage.URL} alt={enlargedImage.name}/>
            </button>
        {/if}
    </div>
</main>
```

I tried putting it in an onMount, I tried setting it in a for loop. Idk what this is its crazy to me.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `splice` is *not* the changed array but an array containing the deleted items, hence why it is the same. Also, `splice` modifies an array in place, so this will permanently alter the source array, which may not be what you want.

If you just want items after the first three, just use `slice` in both cases.

If you really do want to delete the items from the source, it should be rather:

```js
images1 = galleryData.splice(0, 3)
images2 = galleryData // or [...galleryData] / galleryData.slice() to copy
```

There also is a function [`toSpliced`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSpliced) which copies the array, removes items and returns said array, which is probably what you expected here.

```js
images1 = galleryData.slice(0, 3)
images2 = galleryData.toSpliced(0, 3)
```

(But as noted, since this does remove from the start, you could just use `slice(3)` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

So, turning my computer on the next day and it's fixed... strange occurrence.

Comment: you can add a more elaborate answer (like, maybe "edit: restarting it fixed") and also add some thought(if any) why you think this might work for others as well :)